# Send email using Mutt in Python

Tags: python, mutt

I'm using Mutt to send an email in a script in Python and it works fine. But when I plug in the putty and the labeling of the script from the putty when the program reaches the sending part of the email with Mutt no send. If you run it directly on Raspbian it does it well.

Why is this? I need to use Putty so I do not have to be always in front of the physical machine.

The code for the program part is this:

```
if distancia > 10 and a == 0: # Si la distancia es mayor que 10cms
           fecha = time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")  # En esta variable se guarda la fecha actual y la hora para renombrar la foto guardada
           fecha_completa = time.strftime("%c")
           print ("La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!") # Se interrumpe el bucle y se muestra un aviso
           GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, True)
           camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg'.format(fecha)) # Se toma una foto
           print("Capturando foto")
           time.sleep(2)
           print("Copiando foto al servidor")
           shutil.copy("/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg".format(fecha), "/var/www/html/Fotos/{}.jpg".format(fecha)) # Se copia a la carpeta del servidor
           time.sleep(1)
           print("Foto guardada")
           print("Enviando foto")
           os.system('echo "La alarma ha sido activada. Fecha de la activacion: {0}" |  mutt -s "Alguien ha abierto la puerta" micorreo@miservidor.com -a /home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{1}.jpg' .format(fecha_completa, fecha)) # Se envia la foto por correo
           print("Foto enviada con exito")                    
           a = 1 # Pongo la variable en 1 para parar el proceso y que no se repita 
           distancia = media_distancia() # Seguimos midiento la distancia
           while distancia < 10: # Pero si la distancia vuelve a ser menor de 10
             break # Se termina este bucle y volvemos al principio nuevamente
```

But for example if I open Putty and write this if I send the mail perfectly:

```
echo "La alarma ha sido activada." |  mutt -s "Alguien ha abierto la puerta" micorreo@miservidor.com
```

I do not know what else to look at and try.

Comment: Does your program run in the same environment (user ID, permissions, envornment variables) as when you log in via SSH?

Comment: Yes, is the same user. User: Pi I dont know why is it...